# python pandasによるデータ処理について

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

色々と調べてみたはいいものの、書き方がつかめずどうしても固まってしまいます。お力添えをよろしくお願いいたします。
各染色体について父由来か母由来どちらの染色体を子孫に渡すかによってどんな能力のパターンがある得るかのシミュレーションです。

chr_effect.txtのようなデータファイルがあります。
animal、pnt、chr1...chr29の31列あり、各animalにつきpntが1と2あります。便宜上最初の5つのanimal（10行）しか表示していませんが、実際には約5,000つのanimal、すなわち10,000行データがあります。

別にchr_pnt.txtのようなファイルがあります。
便宜上最初の10行しか表示していませんが、実際には100,000行×29列（chr1...chr29）のデータで、pntを示す1もしくは2が入っています。

やりたいことは、以下のような処理です。

1. chr_pntの各要素（chrとpntで一意的に定まる）に対応するchr_effectの値を抽出する。
2. 取り出したchr_effectの値からchr1...chr29までの和を算出する。
3. 算出した和（100,000個）の平均値と標準偏差を返す。
4. 以上の処理をすべてのanimalごとに行い、ファイル出力する。

出力したいファイルのイメージはsolutions.txtです。
説明がわかりにくくて申し訳ないです。

わたし個人では、恥ずかしながら以下のようにデータ読み込みの段階で思考が固まってしまいます。

```
import pandas as pd

chr_effect = pd.read_table('chr_effect.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
chr_pnt = pd.read_table('chr_pnt.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

**chr_effect.txt**

```
animal  pnt chr1    chr2    chr3    chr4    chr5    chr6    chr7    chr8    chr9    chr10   chr11   chr12   chr13   chr14   chr15   chr16   chr17   chr18   chr19   chr20   chr21   chr22   chr23   chr24   chr25   chr26   chr27   chr28   chr29
27790   1   -3.249619881    1.776331581 -2.24113552 -4.817298276    -5.48548554 -1.759651526    5.334048371 3.891744788 1.884854677 -3.242535628    3.756604968 2.986742453 0.612356541 -2.86922751 4.352907409 0.90651085  -0.412862385    0.296373936 -5.889000773    -0.68745163 0.298499644 0.814954378 -0.095186506    0.865718907 2.540816382 5.789061632 -0.559834391    -2.53661836 0.751069038
27790   2   -0.390512283    0.3496771   -2.139579662    -4.59481831 -0.776924186    -0.35638789 -0.526063862    -0.477037798    -1.569054067    -2.90589106 -1.465912498    -3.364848089    0.975073498 -9.574933303    -2.323818571    -2.219380737    -3.775384093    -0.309000541    -0.003886077    1.91834523  -0.124754068    2.23336583  -2.7314078  -1.352587759    -2.121087552    -0.59768476 0.519127176 5.32087313  1.659182504
75952   1   1.860075236 -1.952826593    7.941593806 6.971151872 -5.39318137 24.5906086  -0.627978002    1.558862775 -2.044366214    1.593249157 -1.53647959 -5.210752328    3.478248395 -5.889005176    -0.485182934    1.525452838 -5.212397443    1.330459383 3.158410718 -1.316064027    3.041514078 2.484066153 -1.601287478    4.598523036 1.176341264 -0.732658875    -1.546846435    -0.241240957    -2.703045534
75952   2   0.07320026  -1.193285236    3.664270318 -1.198182299    -3.285812454    -7.21470412 1.759143544 7.648100385 1.693592132 0.946791605 -2.87792026 -2.67183088 -1.945447857    2.474190902 -2.621106236    -2.764357816    -2.279304115    0.00797417  0.663827378 1.58174674  1.271269494 1.272317695 1.142039742 0.076808881 -0.46131242 3.365393607 -1.174178405    -2.626477213    -1.37721366
90414   1   1.739067807 2.705188308 -1.245923538    -0.002399875    -2.599279152    -0.154139815    0.303458033 2.786962772 -2.988691596    0.725134479 -1.551469947    1.406454822 1.488023864 0.978901455 1.780002113 -5.183237296    -1.602299904    0.057587453 4.119123527 -3.148129947    -0.699950319    -0.354722639    0.366632135 4.998152571 1.543905898 3.172006996 -5.345136372    -0.056620664    2.422692998
90414   2   -2.519037307    -0.926182651    0.66829595  0.083873692 -3.127323408    -7.296881507    -0.797579   -1.692284026    0.446947886 -2.593041865    -4.321641322    1.195738671 -1.478727635    4.047270398 2.312901751 -5.3839035  -0.904768118    -3.425975528    -0.418056083    0.648341358 -0.674819627    -1.525995063    0.219910922 0.381569648 -1.513227344    2.566777598 -2.742408197    2.510699832 -1.25012918
90470   1   1.451065566 7.687896532 1.118122984 0.217045435 -4.390935698    -2.358229388    -8.346397709    2.006546339 5.738527934 -3.025387626    -4.028971005    1.712205845 3.627846534 6.986557249 0.963232976 -6.304871835    0.176607468 0.800108489 -0.063414724    6.655480908 -3.68568447 -1.681859217    0.952996904 -3.51742161 -1.585046358    -0.40142409 -1.222321719    5.864682736 0.77443274
90470   2   -3.236474166    -0.828191866    0.864194126 -2.386854158    -5.98932058 -4.859134618    -1.443351926    0.280750195 7.801439742 -4.921804746    1.155552973 1.624703212 -0.895162234    -5.903743854    0.901627188 0.187514121 -2.314349528    -5.426454814    3.349431154 6.005233669 -1.902131074    -1.325578071    0.787564088 -0.522419842    -1.345004348    1.169492376 1.537055754 6.767023934 -3.057591512
102853  1   0.01378943  10.9234678  1.456693154 0.034962635 -5.202454665    -1.662830588    -4.066262419    10.26374255 6.980704894 -1.44364735 -10.15811404    -4.508814067    4.862243682 7.606665536 -0.010935424    -1.73585101 -0.57417706 -1.087272208    4.78751793  7.514152847 -1.479511504    -1.681859217    0.472674332 -0.056568908    -3.122885588    4.59333307  2.501062924 2.730274228 0.727288217
102853  2   1.398403246 1.072480483 -8.505226254    2.64111658  -2.297556361    -1.40125181 -0.318009921    13.65483956 -0.776215002    1.719216586 -3.03228246 -5.971878011    -0.004130784    2.885798136 2.377923162 0.57592465  -3.414375536    -2.701702732    3.752473244 0.186915701 3.673363686 -2.915896525    0.89251478  5.26937868  -1.79715952 2.484896944 -1.231909699    2.871125798 1.623539915
```

**chr_pnt.txt**

```
chr1    chr2    chr3    chr4    chr5    chr6    chr7    chr8    chr9    chr10   chr11   chr12   chr13   chr14   chr15   chr16   chr17   chr18   chr19   chr20   chr21   chr22   chr23   chr24   chr25   chr26   chr27   chr28   chr29
2   2   1   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   1   2   1   2   2   1   1   2
1   2   2   1   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1
1   1   2   2   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   1   2   2   1   2   2   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   2   1   2   2   2   1   2   2   1   1   2   1   1   2   2
1   2   2   1   1   2   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   2   1   1   2   2   1   1   2   2   2   1   2   1
2   1   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   2   2   1   1   2   2   2   1   1   1   1
2   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   2   2   2   1   1   2   1   1   2   2   1   2   2   2   1   1   2
1   2   1   2   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   1   1   2   2   1   1   2   2   1   2   1   1   1   2   1
2   2   2   2   1   1   1   2   1   2   2   2   1   1   2   2   2   1   2   1   1   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   2   2   1   2   1   2   1   2   1   2   1   1   2   1   1   2   1   1   1
```

**solutions.txt**

```
animal  average std
27790   -13.80468698    10.76483559
75952   11.4056846  18.58066141
90414   -10.91855174    8.140109257
90470   -3.89969823 11.36792823
102853  20.69108446 11.8625067
```

Comment: ファイル中の短縮化された名前とか内容や範囲の分からない数字の数や並びよりも、大まかに何をしようとしていて、どういう性質のデータにどのような処理を行いたいか、何を導き出したいか、といったことを説明するか、それをしている記事への紹介リンクを追記すると良いかもしれません。例えば省略名の基が何で如何いう性質等を持っていてどのように分類や組み合わせがされているかといったことでも説明されていると助言や回答が出やすくなると思われます。

Comment: chr_effect.txt, chr_pnt.txt で計算すると solutions.txt の答えになるはず, ということでしょうか？ もしそうなら average のどれかひとつの項目について計算手順示してもらうと分かりやすいかも

Comment: 「データ読み込みの段階で思考が固まってしまいます」とのことですが、調べたことは何もありませんか？ また、「chr_pntの各要素（chrとpntで一意的に定まる）に対応するchr_effectの値」がよく分かりませんでした。「chrとpntで一意的に定まる」について具体的に説明することは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

手順通りに処理を行うとすれば以下の通り(質問に記載されている `solutions.txt` の内容と処理結果が異なっていますけれども)。

```py
import pandas as pd

chr_effect = pd.read_table('chr_effect.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
chr_pnt = pd.read_table('chr_pnt.txt', delim_whitespace=True)

def mapping(animal):
    a = animal.set_index('pnt')
    return chr_pnt.apply(lambda c: c.apply(lambda x: a.loc[x, c.name]))\
                  .sum(axis=1).agg(average='mean', std='std')

chrx = chr_effect.groupby('animal').apply(mapping)
print(chrx)
```

| animal | average | std |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27790 | -18.5713 | 7.74195 |
| 75952 | 15.9058 | 19.3923 |
| 90414 | -8.52192 | 8.27256 |
| 90470 | -7.5583 | 11.9928 |
| 102853 | 20.3525 | 8.98747 |

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'というエラーが出たので、aggの中を、agg(['mean', 'std'])とすることで無事solutionsが得られました。

Comment: おそらく、Pandas のバージョンが最新ではないのかと思います。機会があれば最新版(2022/12/13 時点では 1.5.2)をインストールしてみて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

「 pandas によるデータ処理」とは言えないかもしれないので御参考です。なお，既に回答された方と標準偏差の値が異なるのは pandas と numpy でデフォルトの計算式が異なるためです。一致させるには`np.std(sum_list)` を `np.std(sum_list, ddof=1)` としてください。とはいえ「データ数: 100,000 」では差はほとんどなくなります。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

chr_effect = pd.read_table('chr_effect.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
chr_pnt = pd.read_table('chr_pnt.txt', delim_whitespace=True)

print('  animal    average        std')
for i in range(0, len(chr_effect.index), 2):
    anml = chr_effect.iloc[i, 0]
    p1 = chr_effect.iloc[i, 2:]
    p2 = chr_effect.iloc[i+1, 2:]
    sum_list = []
    for cp in chr_pnt.to_numpy():
        sum_list.append(p1[cp == 1].sum() + p2[cp == 2].sum())
    print(f'{anml:8d} {np.mean(sum_list):10.4f} {np.std(sum_list):10.4f}')
```

```
  animal    average        std
   27790   -18.5713     7.3447
   75952    15.9058    18.3972
   90414    -8.5219     7.8480
   90470    -7.5583    11.3774
  102853    20.3525     8.5263
```

（追記）
chr_pnt.txt を 100,000行に増やして処理時間を計測すると，私の環境（MacOS13(M1), Python 3.10.8）で 30秒ほどでした。animal 数 5,000では単純計算で 500分になります。そこで，下記のように内積計算に変更したところ処理時間は約20分の1（1.6秒）になりました。

```
    # p1 = chr_effect.iloc[i, 2:]
    # p2 = chr_effect.iloc[i+1, 2:]
    p1 = chr_effect.iloc[i, 2:].to_numpy()
    p2 = chr_effect.iloc[i+1, 2:].to_numpy()

        # sum_list.append(p1[cp == 1].sum() + p2[cp == 2].sum())
        sum_list.append(p1 @ (2 - cp) + p2 @ (cp - 1))
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。無事解を得ることができました。また、処理速度の改善法まで示していただきとても助かりました。

Answer (score 0):

> 色々と調べてみたはいいものの、書き方がつかめず

以下は総和の算出の手順です。あとは同じようにできるはず

---

animal ＆ pnt ごとに管理されているので
① まず chr_pnt を pnt ごとにそれぞれ集計 (ch29 まで 29項目)

```py
print((dfpnt == 1).sum(axis=0).to_list())   # pnt == 1 の場合
# [5, 4, 4, 4, 7, 6, 5, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 4, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 9, 6, 7]
```

② chr_effect を pnt ごとに抽出して

```py
display(dfeff[dfeff.pnt == 1])
```

| animal | pnt | chr1 | chr2 | chr3 | chr4 | chr5 | chr6 | chr7 | chr8 | chr9 | chr10 | chr11 | chr12 | chr13 | chr14 | chr15 | chr16 | chr17 | chr18 | chr19 | chr20 | chr21 | chr22 | chr23 | chr24 | chr25 | chr26 | chr27 | chr28 | chr29 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27790 | 1 | -3.24962 | 1.77633 | -2.24114 | -4.8173 | -5.48549 | -1.75965 | 5.33405 | 3.89174 | 1.88485 | -3.24254 | 3.7566 | 2.98674 | 0.612357 | -2.86923 | 4.35291 | 0.906511 | -0.412862 | 0.296374 | -5.889 | -0.687452 | 0.2985 | 0.814954 | -0.0951865 | 0.865719 | 2.54082 | 5.78906 | -0.559834 | -2.53662 | 0.751069 |
| 75952 | 1 | 1.86008 | -1.95283 | 7.94159 | 6.97115 | -5.39318 | 24.5906 | -0.627978 | 1.55886 | -2.04437 | 1.59325 | -1.53648 | -5.21075 | 3.47825 | -5.88901 | -0.485183 | 1.52545 | -5.2124 | 1.33046 | 3.15841 | -1.31606 | 3.04151 | 2.48407 | -1.60129 | 4.59852 | 1.17634 | -0.732659 | -1.54685 | -0.241241 | -2.70305 |
| 90414 | 1 | 1.73907 | 2.70519 | -1.24592 | -0.00239988 | -2.59928 | -0.15414 | 0.303458 | 2.78696 | -2.98869 | 0.725134 | -1.55147 | 1.40645 | 1.48802 | 0.978901 | 1.78 | -5.18324 | -1.6023 | 0.0575875 | 4.11912 | -3.14813 | -0.69995 | -0.354723 | 0.366632 | 4.99815 | 1.54391 | 3.17201 | -5.34514 | -0.0566207 | 2.42269 |
| 90470 | 1 | 1.45107 | 7.6879 | 1.11812 | 0.217045 | -4.39094 | -2.35823 | -8.3464 | 2.00655 | 5.73853 | -3.02539 | -4.02897 | 1.71221 | 3.62785 | 6.98656 | 0.963233 | -6.30487 | 0.176607 | 0.800108 | -0.0634147 | 6.65548 | -3.68568 | -1.68186 | 0.952997 | -3.51742 | -1.58505 | -0.401424 | -1.22232 | 5.86468 | 0.774433 |
| 102853 | 1 | 0.0137894 | 10.9235 | 1.45669 | 0.0349626 | -5.20245 | -1.66283 | -4.06626 | 10.2637 | 6.9807 | -1.44365 | -10.1581 | -4.50881 | 4.86224 | 7.60667 | -0.0109354 | -1.73585 | -0.574177 | -1.08727 | 4.78752 | 7.51415 | -1.47951 | -1.68186 | 0.472674 | -0.0565689 | -3.12289 | 4.59333 | 2.50106 | 2.73027 | 0.727288 |

③ あとは乗算

```py
df1,df2 = (dfeff抽出分 * dfpnt集計分 for p in (1,2))
dfsum = df1 + df2

# pnt1, pnt2 を分けることなく加算する場合
dfsum = sum(dfeff抽出分 * dfpnt集計分 for p in (1,2))
```

以上をまとめると

```py
import pandas as pd
dfeff = pd.read_csv(chr_effect, sep='\s+', index_col='animal')
dfpnt = pd.read_csv(chr_pnt, sep='\s+')

dfsum = sum(dfeff.loc[dfeff.pnt == p, 'chr1':'chr29']
                 .mul((dfpnt == p).sum(axis='index'), axis='columns')
                                                      for p in (1,2))

display(dfsum.sum(axis='columns'))
# animal
# 27790    -185.712504
# 75952     159.058371
# 90414     -85.219206
# 90470     -75.583044
# 102853    203.524688
# dtype: float64
```

---

##### 追記

chr_pnt 件数での平均の場合

```py
print(dfpnt.shape)   # (10, 29)
len(dfpnt)   # 10

display(dfsum.sum(axis='columns') / len(dfpnt))
# animal
# 27790    -18.571250
# 75952     15.905837
# 90414     -8.521921
# 90470     -7.558304
# 102853    20.352469
# dtype: float64
```